# Adapter: male pvc pipe to female metal outdoor faucet

Tags: plumbing, adapter

I have an outdoor faucet that recently had a metal pipe (age caused it to crack) replaced with a pvc pipe. The faucet that is attached is metal, so it didn't leak before; it leaks now because it is a metal to pvc connection. The pvc pipe has a male threaded end and the faucet is female threaded. I need an adapter that is female on the pvc side and male on the metal side, but I have not been able to find one. All I can find is an adapter that has the pvc side that slides inside. I haven't been able to find it anywhere. Does what I need actually exist? Or do I need to fit two adapters together to get the right connection....
Thanks in advance

Comment: Pictures always help when dealing with adapters.

Comment: It is unclear as to how you think an adapter is the solution to a leak.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for an extender of sorts. I've used fittings like that which also change pipe size at the same time: for example, an adapter with 1/2" female thread going to 1/4" male thread. These are usually brass. I haven't seen one in which the pipe size does not change. You'd probably have to use a regular threaded coupler followed by a nipple of whatever length suits you.

The real problem, though, is that you have a plastic-to-metal threaded connection that's leaking -- is that right? You don't need extra fittings to fix this. All you need is some pipe joint compound, sometimes called "pipe dope." Choose one that includes PTFE (Teflon). Disassemble the leaking joint, dry the male thread, apply the compound, reassemble. Wipe away the excess compound and test for leaks. Chances are high this is all you'll need.

Comment: Yeah the pipe size doesn't change, it's just the leak that is bothersome. I will definitely try the joint compound first before buying fittings I don't need. I have some on hand. Thank you!

Comment: Teflon tape may also work but I think dope is better when using threaded fittings in plastic, less chance to break the female.

Comment: In my experience dope seals the joint _every_ time and only makes a mess if I applied too much, whereas teflon tape never makes a mess but sometimes doesn't achieve a leak-free seal. I find the chance of small mess to be greatly preferable over the chance of having to re-do an assembly because a joint in the middle leaks! :-)